# replace one amchart with another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently, I have this amchart below.

[image]

And I want to create another amchart with the same values. (I just want to replace the graph).

The new graphic is here -> https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-graph/?theme=material#code

my code Angular:

```
prepareDataForTemplate(res) {
    this.showLineChart = false;
    if (res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00') {
        this.lines = [];


        this.dataForChart.data.splice(0, this.dataForChart.data.length);
        this.dataForChart.date.splice(0, this.dataForChart.date.length);
        this.dataForChart.data.push(...res.HISTDEV.VALUE.map(x => x.COURS));
        this.dataForChart.date.push(...res.HISTDEV.VALUE.map(x => x.DATE));
        this.showLineChart = true;

        if (res.HISTDEV.VALUE.length > 0) {
            this.yMin = res.HISTDEV.VALUE[0].COURS;
            this.yMax = res.HISTDEV.VALUE[0].COURS;
            res.HISTDEV.VALUE.map(value => {
                if (value.COURS < this.yMin) {
                    this.yMin = value.COURS;
                }
                if (value.COURS > this.yMax) {
                    this.yMax = value.COURS;
                }
            })
        }


        this.loadChart();


    } else {

    }

}
```

Then, the method loadChart(), it is the graph that I want to change...

```
loadChart() {
    let datePipe = this.datePipe;
    let decimalPipe = this.decimalPipe;
    let leleuxNumPipe = this.leleuxNumPipe;

    this.lineChartReturn = {
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis',
            position: function(pt) {
                return [pt[0], '10%'];
            },

            formatter: function(params) {
                return datePipe.transform(params[0].name) + "<br/>" +
                    params[0].marker + " " +
                    params[0].seriesName + " <b>" +
                    leleuxNumPipe.transform(decimalPipe.transform(params[0].value, '1.2-2')) + "</b";
            }


        },
        title: {
            left: 'center',
            text: '',
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            //show: true,
            data: this.dataForChart.date,

            axisLabel: {
                formatter: function(value, index) {
                    return datePipe.transform(value);
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value',
            min: this.yMin,
            max: this.yMax,
            //show: true
            axisLabel: {
                formatter: function(value, index) {
                    return leleuxNumPipe.transform(decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2'))
                }
            }
        },
        dataZoom: [{
            type: 'inside',
            start: 0,
            end: 100
        }, {
            start: 0,
            end: 10,
            handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9v-1.3H9.3v1.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4v1.3h1.3v-1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
            handleSize: '80%',
            handleStyle: {
                color: '#fff',
                shadowBlur: 3,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
                shadowOffsetX: 2,
                shadowOffsetY: 2
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            name: 'Amount',
            type: 'line',
            smooth: true,
            symbol: 'none',
            sampling: 'average',
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, .6)', // 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
            },
            areaStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.15)',
                origin: 'start'
            },
            lineStyle: {
                // width: 1,
                color: 'rgba(255, 152, 0, .6)',
            },
            data: this.dataForChart.data,
        }, ]


    };
}
```

In the doc amchart -> https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-graph/?theme=material#code

I don't understand how to I adapt the code from amcharts with my method loadchart() ?

Sorry, if I ask you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to amcharts myself, but I'll give it a try.

First, I'm assuming that if you have a chart that you want to replace, you can save a reference to it, that would look something like this:

```
  private chart: am4charts.XYChart;
```

And when you create your chart for the first time, wherever it is, you can do somthing like this:

```
this.chart = am4core.createFromConfig(this.lineChartReturn, 'htmlIdReference', am4charts.XYChart);
```

If your setup looks something like that, then you should be able to just use the `dispose` function, and then create it again with the new `lineChartReturn` you generate in `loadChart`

```
loadChart() {
    if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.dispose();
    }

    // your current code to generate new this.lineChartReturn

    // Then just create it again using the createFromConfig
    this.chart = am4core.createFromConfig(this.lineChartReturn, 'htmlIdReference', am4charts.XYChart);
}
```